# What are the wrong assumptions made in Anagaxoras' model in his calculation of Earth-Sun distance?

Tags: cosmology, greek-mathematics

The greek mathematician Anaxagoras made an inacurrate evaluation of the distance between the Sun and the Earth. I've been thinking about his work and would like to know what exactly was wrong about his calculation.

### Facts:

- Syene is a city located (nearly) on the Cancer tropic, which means that on June $21$ at noon, the Sun is at the zenith of, say, an object. More specifically, the object has no shadow. On the other hand, Alexandria is located $800$km ($=5000$ stadia) northwards from Syene.
- In this configuration, Anaxagoras has measured an angle of $7,2°$  between the vertical in Alexandria and the direction of the sunrays shining in Alexandria.

### Assumptions (of Anaxagoras):

Anaxagoras assumes Earth is planar and that the Sun is a point (and as a consequence of it, *that the sunrays shine the Earth in a conic "divergent" beam*). Actually I don't know (maybe I should read in its writings) if Anaxagoras made the assumption that the Sun is a point, or just if he made the assumption that sunrays arrive in a conic "divergent" beam.

Anyway, the figure below illustrates Anaxagoras' assumption that the Earth is flat and the conic beam of sunrays. You can ignore the fact that the Sun is a point (since we are not sure of this fact).
[image]

### Defending Anaxagoras (and trying to understand which assumption of his model was wrong):

While it is an evidence that his first assumption of Earth flatness was completely wrong, the other assumption (as we saw) has two versions, which are both viable in my opinion.

- If he was (only) thinking that sunrays were coming in a conic beam towards the surface of the Earth, we can see this assumption is not far from reality as illustrated in the figure below (the first scheme is what really happens (in our $2024$ model), the second one is what Anaxagoras thought).[image: two conic beam from the Sun, reality and Anaxagoras]
- if he was assuming that the Sun is a point, again it is not a bad assumption. Isn't that the assumption we make when we nowadays say the sunrays come parallel to the surface of the Earth ? I am pretty sure it is the same.

---

So, my question is which assumption was wrong in Anaxagoras model ? Only that the Earth is flat ? Or is there any other wrong assumption ?

Note: We cannot say "assuming a small distance between the Earth and the Sun was a wrong assumption from Anaxagoras" since this distance is exactly what he was aiming to calculate.

I don't know if thanking in advance is allowed in this section (thanks in advance anyway).

Comment: No writings of Anaxagoras survive, and secondary sources only mention that, according to him, the Earth is flat and the Sun is bigger than Peloponnesus. We do not know what else was wrong with Anaxagoras's model because we do not know anything else about Anaxagoras's model. There are only speculations about eclipse, gnomons, etc., including your 7.2°, see [Couprie, Anaxagoras and the Size of the Sun](https://www.academia.edu/52614185/Anaxagoras_and_the_Size_of_the_Sun). What we do know is that in Aristarchus's later estimates the main problem was not with the model but with the measured angles

Comment: The wrong assumption is that the Earth is flat. The observations he mentions are essentially the same that Eratosthenes later used to determine the radius of the Earth. The distance to the Sun could not be determined with any reasonable accuracy by the methods which were available at that time.

Comment: @Conifold I don't understand your last sentence. Isn't $7.2°$ the right angle ? I think it is the angle later used by Eratosthenes (in his sucessful deduction of the Earth circumference).

Comment: There is no known connection between 7.2° and Anaxagoras, and Eratosthenes obviously did not assume that the Earth is flat.